# Unable to modify table

Tags: mysql

I am working MySQL database and want to untick allow nulls from the table.
Here is the [screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLw5a.png) 
However it is giving this error-

> 'Resume' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'sscyop', table 'ResumeDB.dbo.Tmp_Resume'; column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Here is the [Screen-shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXAOy.png)

Comment: If you want to 'untick allow nulls' then it requires something in that field. Can you put a default in the field or populate null values with something prior to clearing out 'allow nulls'?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Tried it but not working.

Comment: So you populated `sscyop` column with values? Then tried unchecking 'allow nulls'?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thanks bro. Worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to uncheck the `allow nulls` checkbox, first populate `sscyop` column null values with data. Then uncheck the `allow nulls` checkbox in design mode.

This should solve your issue.